# Pull-down resistor with LED on a logic input

Tags: voltage, led, pulldown

Imagine I have the following circuit:

A register (74LS377N) has the inputs connected to a bus.

In the picture, BUS0 is pulled down with a 10k resistor, so if nobody outputs to it the register will read 0 in the first input.

BUS7 is connected to an LED in series with a resistor, so I can visualize when that pin is high or low. The resistor of the LED is quite high because for lower values of R the LED is too bright, so I have empirically determined that 5k works well for the LED.

Now, this is a green LED that has a forward voltage between 2-3V, enough to be interpreted as HIGH for the register.

My question is: When the bus is in high impedance, would the LED + resistor correctly pull down the voltage to 0V, or because of the forward voltage of the LED the input might be higher and therefore cause garbage in the input of the register?

Should I put a 10k resistor in parallel to the LED+5kR or is the LED+5kR enough to force a 0 in the input when the bus is in high impedance?

According to the datasheet, a LOW level has a maximum input voltage < 0.8V and a high level has a minimum input voltage of 2V, so the forward voltage of the LED is what scares me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED and resistor cannot reliably pull down the BUS7 input to the 74LS377 to a logic LOW.

The LS family have a high input leakage current out of a LOW input. The [TI 74LS377 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls377.pdf) states that an input driver must sink 400 uA max. from the input pin to GND to drive the input LOW. (It must source only 20 uA max. to drive it HIGH.)

The LED will always have too high a voltage drop to pull your input LOW, especially sinking the relatively high current of an LS input.

Instead, add a pull-down resistor from BUS7 to GND, in parallel with the LED circuit.

The pull-down resistor value depends on (a) the leakage current from the 74LS377 input and (b) any current from the BUS7 driver, be it leakage or otherwise.

Allowing for dropping 0.5 V when sinking 0.5 mA, you'd need a 1K pull-down resistor. This will load the circuit that normally drives BUS7 so you'll have to weigh that up if that's possible. Using values like 10K will just make the units unreliable if you're building a number of them.

If you can use a newer family like a 74HC(T) gate, the input leakage currents are much lower and higher pull-down resistor values can be used.

Answer (score 0):

> *Should I put a 10k resistor in parallel to the LED+5kR or the LED+5kR
> is enough to force a 0 in the input when the bus is in High Impedance?*

Yes, you should if you want to avoid reading an ambiguous value.